# Updating database domains, giver error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; Line 1

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Hi I have an old website that I would like to use on a new domain. I have created the new database, updated the wp-config, and now just need to update the domain names inside the database.

When I run my SQL query, it gives me an error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''http://datenetworks.net''http://consumerdating.com') FROM wp_options WHERE opt' at line 1

This is the SQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://datenetworks.net', 'http://consumerdating.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://datenetworks.net','http://consumerdating.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://datenetworks.net', 'http://consumerdating.com');
```

Please let me know what the issue is.

Thanks!

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample

Comment: From the error it seems that you didn't input the provided query. Instead you have a query which has too many single-quotes and no comma between the two urls.

Comment: I get this error after selecting "Simulate Query" in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: There is a comma between the two URL's in the query, it's just not shown in the error prompt. Please take a look at my SQL Query, as it seems correct. I'm not sure what the issue is with the code.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct SQL? Because the error says near `FROM wp_options WHERE opt` but that doesn't appear to be in any of the 3 queries you posted... in fact, `FROM` is nowhere to be found...

Comment: I've used this same SQL Query a few years back, and it worked totally fine. I think this is correct when you just want to update domains.. I'm stumped as to what this error is.

Comment: I'm not saying that your query doesn't work... I'm just saying that the ones you posted aren't causing the error because it's obviously not the same query. Please check that out!

Comment: Also, `@` me because I don't get notifications if you simply comment. You get notifications because this is your own question.

Comment: That makes sense, but this error is for this exact query, which is why I'm stumped.

Comment: @Zeke - Sorry I'm new to this site. This error is caused by this exact query, which is why I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: Okay, can I see a screenshot (feel free to edit it just so I can see the query box and error) of phpMyAdmin when the error appears? Because although I want to believe what you're saying, phpMyAdmin doesn't generate random inexistent queries... furthermore, `FROM` is usually in a `SELECT` statement, I'm as shocked as you are if that query really does produce the error in question.

Comment: @Zeke It seems like I need 10 reputation points to post images.. I have a screenshot link ready, not sure how to post it. Is there another way I can contact you?

Comment: @Zeke [link]((https://image.prntscr.com/image/plUl8ypbTjKh9stcidUelA.jpg)

Comment: Close enough... I just saw it... this is very confusing. Did you try other simulations prior to this one?

Comment: I did not. I just created a new database, imported my old SQL file, updated the wp-config file to the new credentials, then ran this query, and keep getting this error. I've read online about how to do this also, and all of the articles have this same code..

Comment: That sounds like a normal routine, and the code looks fine... what's your current MySQL version? Maybe if you over-specify the tables and use backticks? Something like `UPDATE \`wp_options\` SET \`wp_options\`.\`option_value\` = replace(\`wp_options\`.\`option_value\`, 'http://datenetworks.net', 'http://consumerdating.com') WHERE \`wp_options\`.\`option_name\` = 'home' OR \`wp_options\`.\`option_name\` = 'siteurl';`... this is a **_long_** shot, like a 100yd field goal.

Comment: I tried that query out also, it gives the same error. Maybe now the code needs a 'from' to have a 'where'? I'm lost. I just checked the MySQL, and I have version 5.6 it seems.

Comment: Ok, honestly, the syntax looks just fine. Even for `UPDATE`. You need `FROM` only for `SELECT`, [as you can see here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php). And that hasn't changed, let alone in version 5.6 where I believe it was introduced. So updating MySQL wouldn't change much... I'll try to simulate the same query on my local server and see what I get.

Comment: Hey, I tried the same syntax (using different columns and values, of course) and it worked. I'm using MySQL 5.7.17 and phpMyAdmin 4.7.7 (latest). This is going to be a longer shot and definitely more tedious, but you can try to update... who knows, it might fix it...

Comment: @Zeke Thanks for doing that, much appreciated. I will try to update (or change) MySQL and phpMyAdmin and see if that does anything. If not, I might just switch hosting companies (currently using HostGator). Something is up with their servers possibly.

Comment: Oh, if you're using a dedicated server you won't have any issues (I have both a local and dedicated server, the latter provided by iWeb, a Canadian company owned by Internap). I personally provide hosting solutions with that server because I manage it myself, so I can directly modify stuff on demand. But if you're hiring a shared server, I'm sorry but I don't think you'll be able to update anything because you'll need root access to do that, and you'll most likely have to compile, provision, and reboot the server. You'll only be able to choose from the installed versions list.

Comment: Also, I did use backticks and over-specify the tables. Just so you know...

Comment: @Zeke Just to be sure, did my original query work for you? Also, which hosting would you recommend? I currently have Hostgator (As stated above) but I might switch to Bluehost or another that allows for better control of the database.

Comment: I can only try the syntax, we do not share the same database so I had to adjust the values and columns to my own tables, but I used the same exact syntax, and it worked. I can also show you what I did if you wish. You can always email me, stackoverflow@snowlinks.net. About the hosting, I'm not sure because I'm not really into that. Ever since I hired a dedicated server from iWeb back in 2014, I completely forgot about hosting. I'm hosting my own stuff and all my customers' websites. So yeah, that's all I can say.

Comment: @VinceMonde any updates?

Comment: @Zeke I talked with the support, it seems I cannot change versions of the MySQL or phpMyAdmin. I was able to get one of the support techs to update all the links manually somehow. I asked how he did it, but they just said they used some tool to do it internally. So one of my website is up. Now, I'm trying to do the same thing (talking with support to update the links again on another website) and they have no idea what I'm talking about now which is hilarious. I honestly have no idea why this syntax is giving me issues. I have the default version of PHP 5.6.

Comment: The syntax is fine and I proved it. So there must be something wrong with that configuration... the fact that they don’t let you do that makes me believe you’re now under a shared server service. Any modification may affect other users, hence why they don’t allow you to do that. I believe you can still install your own copy of phpMyAdmin on a website and set it up to work with your databases, but MySQL and PHP are another story. PHP doesn’t matter in this case, but I’m using PHP 7.2. If you’re gonna switch, try iWeb, if any of their services are within your budget.

Comment: @Zeke Hey just wanted to give an update. So I went ahead and ran the same syntax in the console (bottom tab of phpMyAdmin, and there were no issues. I asked around and It could've been a delimiter issue or something of that nature. So now everything works, I just need to use the console to run my syntax instead of in the SQL query box. Weird, but it works.

Comment: That is the weirdest thing ever. I'm definitely gonna try it out. I'm glad it works though, good luck with your project!